# debugging firebase functions on localhost Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-cloud-firestore, nodemon, firebase-cli

I am trying to debug firestore functions locally. I can run them using the command `npm run serve` but when trying to run the command via nodemon ispect i.e. `npm run debug` I am getting following error

```js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/23314e94-db99-49e6-961b-010d3a93516c
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\xyz\fs-functions\functions\serve'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

here is my package.json's script content

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "debug": "nodemon --inspect serve",
  },
```